# How to tell a Windows service to restart or reload its configuration?

Tags: winapi, events, windows-services

I have a GUI application that is used to configure a windows service and I want to start, stop or restart this service from thing GUI application.

One of the problems is that this service can run in two modes: windows service or manually from command line (so you have a console).

Now, I am looking for a way to communicate this, a way that would work in both cases.

It may be helpfull to specify that the service process already has and even handler that is dealing with:

- `CTRL_C_EVENT`
- `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`
- `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`
- `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`
- `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`

It would be quite easy to extend the handler if I knew what event will be triggered by the service restart option. Still, I should be able to trigger the same event from my GUI application so I will be able to tell the "server" to restart itself even if it is running in background.

The best is would be if I could do this without having to detect in which mode the server application is running.

Answer (score 2):

There are [Service Trigger Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that your service can listen for, and then your GUI can send an event.  In particular, you want to register for an `SERVICE_TRIGGER_TYPE_CUSTOM` trigger, which causes your service to listen for an ETW event; your GUI code would then write the ETW event to trigger the event.

Comment: Thanks, Eric this seems to be what I am looking for. I hope I can listed for these even if I'm not running as a service. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

There is no service restart action.  All you would do is stop the service normally, then start the service normally afterwards.  That is all the SCM restart does internally, it is just exposed as a single operation in the SCM UI instead of as two separate options.